# How does JavaScript treat parameters in nested functions?

Tags: javascript

It is one of the most odd behaviors I've stumbled in my JavaScript learning,

this is example:

```
function multiplier(factor) {
  return function(number) {
    return number * factor;
  };
}

var twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
// → 10
```

this is an example taken from the book [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html), the author explained it in a confusing way, that makes it more odd:

> In the example, multiplier returns a frozen chunk of code that gets
>   stored in the twice variable. The last line then calls the value in
>   this variable, causing the frozen code (return number * factor;) to be
>   activated. It still has access to the factor variable from the
>   multiplier call that created it, and in addition it gets access to the
>   argument passed when unfreezing it, 5, through its number
>   parameter.

Could anyone explain how the second call of `multiplier` function in `twice()` 
assigned the parameter to the nested function, and what if there were more nested function, what is the concept and the rule for this?

Comment: Have you ever played with C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, multiplier returns a function when it is called. Thus, when you invoke multiplier and store it in twice, a function is being stored. 
You can look at it this way,
When you execute console.log(twice(5), it's like you're executing console.log(multiplier(2)(5))

Answer (score 0):

multiplier function is returning the function inside it. So, in the first call `twice` will be equal to the function returned by the multiplier function like below :

```
twice = function(number) {
         return number * factor;
        };
```

Here the value of `factor` is `2` that is passed to the multiplier function in the first call and will be accessible in the function inside it even after the execution, this is the concept of [Closures in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Second time, when you call `twice(5)`, it returns the product of `5` which is passed to `twice` and `factor` which was passed earlier in the first call. Hence the product is `10`.